# Why do AutoFac delegate factories registered InstancePerRequest get called each time a type is injected

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, autofac, factories

I'm using Delegate Factories to create an object using a static .Create() function because the creation of the object is somewhat heavy and doesn't belong in a constructor.  This object (UserToken) is used on every Mvc Controller.

I've noticed in my code example , when registering with an AutoFac delegate function to create UserToken the UserToken.Create() is called multiple times per request. I expected it to only be called once per request and having the resulting UserToken stored and re-used by the builder.  What am I missing here? I only want UserToken.Create called once per request.

```
builder.Register<Func<HttpContextBase, IUnitOfWork, UserAccountToken>>(
    c => {
            var db = c.Resolve<IUnitOfWork>();
            var hc = c.Resolve<HttpContextBase>();

            return (context, database) => { return UserAccountToken.Create(hc, db); };
         }).InstancePerRequest();

builder.Register<UserAccountToken>(
    c => {
            var db = c.Resolve<IUnitOfWork>();
            var hc = c.Resolve<HttpContextBase>();

            return UserAccountToken.Create(hc, db);

         }).As<IUserAccountToken>().InstancePerRequest();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you are using the registered type `Func<HttpContextBase, IUnitOfWork, UserAccountToken>`. You're basically returning a function that receives two parameters which you are never using. (`context` and `database`).

I'm assuming to create an `IUserAccountToken` you only need to call `UserAccountToken.Create()` and pass its corresponding parameters. If that is the case you only need the second registration.

It would only be:

```
builder.Register<UserAccountToken>(c =>
{
    var db = c.Resolve<IUnitOfWork>();
    var hc = c.Resolve<HttpContextBase>();

    return UserAccountToken.Create(hc, db);

})
    .As<IUserAccountToken>()
    .InstancePerRequest();
```